# Getting exception "Connection Reset" when trying to fetch response code using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get response code using httpurlconnection but getting "**Connection Reset**" every time.

Here is the code I am using,

```
try {
    String url = "https://www.northerntrust.com/asia-pac/home";

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
    conn.connect();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

   } catch(Exception e) {
          logger.error("Caught exception : {}", e.getMessage);
   }
```

The exception says : **"Stack trace : java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)"**,
**Connection reset**

Why am I getting this error ?

This is happening for these urls as well :

1. https://www.comerica.com/business.html
2. https://www.pbcu.com/

Comment: `conn` or `connection`?

Comment: connection it is, it's just a variable name.

Comment: I know what it is, but you build up one object and invoke `.getResponseCode();` on another, which does not exist in the context.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry for the error. Appreciate your observation. Thanks.

Comment: The peer reset the connection. Examine its logs for why.

Comment: I tried to send the request but used a 3d party http client. For the link https://www.pbcu.com/ everything worked, I got some html as response and response code was "200 OK". For the link https://www.comerica.com/business.html I got as well "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error". I believe that you are trying to pretend to be browser "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" but the site figures that you are not and refuses you.

Comment: I second @MichaelGantman. It could be the case and is fairly common when the site detects that the request is not coming from a browser or an allowed bot.

Comment: @MichaelGantman I tried without setting "User-Agent", but still it failed.
Can you please guide me with a workthrough.

Comment: @DeepanshuGautam - Setting "User-Agent" is fine and you should do it. But sending request from your code and try and pretend to be a request from a browser (an impersonation) is a fine art. I would suggest that you do send request from the browser first and intercept it and see all the headers that browser sets and try an immetate it in your request. You might succeed or not, depending on safisticattion of defence your target site has. In any case I suggest you use 3d party HttpClient such as Apache Http client to send your request. I use MgntUtils library (written by me) as my Http client

Comment: @DeepanshuGautam: Websites are meant to be accessed via browser or via google bot for indexing. In order to prevent unwanted scraping calls, websites generally have a mechanism to either blacklist the caller i.p or rejecting the request in case the website identifies the caller as bot/unwanted etc.

Comment: BTW MgntUtils Javadoc could be found here: http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html and the library itself here: https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases or here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils